# Sanic Python: Delete File after sending it to a client

Tags: python, sanic

I'm running a Python Server with Sanic, and when a client requests a file, the server creates this file and sends it to the client. For now, I've been using middleware:
`@app.listener('before_server_stop')`
to cleanup those files when the server stops.

Obviously, this solution is not nice, and I would prefer to clean them up immediately, after sending the response with the file to the client.
Is there a way to do this?

The code in question:

```
@app.route('/getFiles', methods=['GET'])
async def getFiles(request):
        //create file
        if os.path.isfile(id+'.txt'):
            return await response.file(id+'.txt')
            // -> best would be to delete file here 

@app.listener('before_server_stop')
//delete all files
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Background tasks are not guaranteed to run after the response is complete if you are using async. I tried this approach and it would sometimes delete the file before it had been served to the requester.

Instead you can use [middleware](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/basics/middleware.html) to run code after the request has been completed. You can also register middleware to run code as the request comes in, before the handler sees it, but you don't need that feature here.

Combined with [blueprints](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/best-practices/blueprints.html#overview), the approach that worked for me is similar to this. I don't know where `id` comes from in your code snippet in the question but the middleware has access to the same `request` object the route handler does so you can just get it the same way.

```
bp = sanic.Blueprint("File", url_prefix="/getFiles")

@bp.get('/')
async def getFiles(request):
    id=getIdFromRequest(request)
    //create file
    if os.path.isfile(id+'.txt'):
        return await response.file(id+'.txt')

@bp.on_response:
async def deleteFileWhenDone(request, response):
    id=getIdFromRequest(request)
    # Make sure response actually succeeded
    if response.status == 200:
        os.remove(id+'.txt')

app.blueprint(bp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **os.remove()** to delete files

```
if os.path.exists(id+'.txt'):
  os.remove(id+'.txt')
```

Steps in your case:

1- Load/read the data file into a variable

2 - Delete the file

3 - **return** the variable content as a HTTP file response, check if in Sanic is something like this in Django:

```
response = HttpResponse(data, [content_type]='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="myfile.txt"'
return response
```

Chech about [content-type/MIME-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basico_sobre_HTTP/MIME_types) file responses

Comment: Hi, I'm doing this in the before_server_stop already, but I want to do this immediately after sending it to the client.

Comment: File Response in HTTP should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great use case for [background tasks](https://sanicframework.org/guide/basics/tasks.html).

```py
async def remove_file(file_name):
    os.remove(file_name)

@app.route('/getFiles', methods=['GET'])
async def getFiles(request):
    if os.path.isfile(id+'.txt'):
        request.app.add_task(remove_file(id+'.txt'))
        return await response.file(id+'.txt')
    return response.text("Nope, no file", status=404)
```